# Macroscopic & Microscopic Electric Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

What are the precise mathematical definitions of the macroscopic & microscopic electric fields? For example, when I study the boundary conditions for an static electric field $\vec{E}$, the textbook refers $\vec{E(\rho)}$ and $\vec{\rho}(\vec{r})$ are macroscopic electric field and charge density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing some neatly defined boundary of scales, if that is what you are looking for.  It doesn't exist.

Electric fields are always photons (and virtual photons), and on earth they are usually photons which were emitted by electrons in atoms.  But we can often ignore the individual photons and focus instead on their behavior en masse.  We can also often ignore the individual source atoms, and focus instead on their behavior en masse.

I believe that the best way to interpret your textbook's use of the word macroscopic would be to consider any electric field in a situation where both of the above approximations are valid to be macroscopic.  If you get into a situation where the field irregularities produced by individual atoms become important, then you might be considering a microscopic field.  And if you reach a scale where the behavior of individual photons and virtual photons become important, you might be studying quantum mechanics rather than any classical electric field at all!